# I've commented QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission but when we upload on play store it still show in permissions

Tags: flutter, dart

I've even deleted the build folder and re-generated the build. this is my manifest file below. Because of that package Playstore is rejecting app again and again can any body help me out.
I've commented QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission but when we upload on play store it still show in permissions I also have permission handler package in project.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cherrybyte.digapplauncher.dig_app_launcher"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>

    <!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />-->
    <!-- For apps with targetSDK=31 (Android 12) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" /> -->

    <application
        android:label="DIGABU"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
<!--        <service-->
<!--            android:name=".NotificationOnKillService"-->
<!--            android:enabled="true"-->
<!--            android:exported="false"/>-->
<!--        <service-->
<!--            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"-->
<!--            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"-->
<!--            android:exported="false"/>-->
<!--        <receiver-->
<!--            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"-->
<!--            android:exported="false"/>-->
<!--        <receiver-->
<!--            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"-->
<!--            android:enabled="false"-->
<!--            android:exported="false">-->
<!--            <intent-filter>-->
<!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />-->
<!--            </intent-filter>-->
<!--        </receiver>-->

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBSeR6VjzmTuVhbxnw6MDRMyTxfkbnm3L8"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <!-- codes for a launcher -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <service
            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>


        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="androidintent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```